# Loop a switch statement Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, switch-statement

Hey this is my first post, i am trying to recreate the google dinosaur game but when i open the page a random animation is chosen but only once i need a way to loop it constantly lets say once a second. The "kubbur" are the cactus in the original game.

```
var kubbur = document.getElementById("kubbur");
var kubbur2 = document.getElementById("kubburTwo");
var kubbur3 = document.getElementById("kubburThree");
var randomKubbur = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); //chooses a random number

switch(randomKubbur) {
    case 0:
            if(kubbur.classList !="animateKubbur1"){
            kubbur.classList.add ("animateKubbur1");
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
            kubbur.classList.remove("animateKubbur1");
            }, 1000)

        break;
    case 1:
            if(kubbur2.classList !="animateKubburTwo"){
            kubbur2.classList.add ("animateKubburTwo");
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
            kubbur2.classList.remove("animateKubburTwo");
            }, 1000)
        break;
    case 2:
            if(kubbur3.classList !="animateKubburThree"){
            kubbur3.classList.add ("animateKubburThree");
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
            kubbur3.classList.remove("animateKubburThree");
            }, 1000)
        break;
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read [help/on-topic] and [ask].

Comment: What is your question? If you are looking for a code review, There is a stack exchange site for that.

Comment: @PaulRooney sorry it is badly worded. I need to loop this on a random time between 700ms to 1200ms and do it continuously. But i have no idea how to.

Comment: If you need a code review I had one for you but question is closed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var kubburs = document.querySelectorAll(".kubbur");

// Create a function
function animate() {
  var classes      = ['animateKubbur1', 'animateKubburTwo', 'animateKubburThree'],
      randomKubbur = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3), // random number between 0-2
      elem         = kubburs[randomKubbur],
      className    = classes[randomKubbur];
      
  elem.classList.add(className);
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.classList.remove(className);
  }, 1000);
  
  // Repeat it after 700-1200 ms
  setTimeout(animate, Math.random() * (1200 - 700) + 700);
}

// Call it
animate();
```

```css
.kubbur { width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #ccc; display: inline-block; }
.animateKubbur1 { background: red; }
.animateKubburTwo { background: green; }
.animateKubburThree { background: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="kubbur"></div>
<div class="kubbur"></div>
<div class="kubbur"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot works good!!